# Populate using mongoose doesn't return targeted ref collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections, one is Credit, another one is User

**credit**

[image]

**users**
[image]

As you can see the credit's userId is the same with users's _id. How can I retrieve credit document when I retrieve that user? I've tried ref in schema but I don't get the data of credit, like so

```
exports.getUser = async function(req, res) {

  const user = await User.findOne({_id: req.query.id})
  .populate('credit')
  .exec()

  res.json(user)
}
```

**CreditSchema**

```
const CreditSchema = new Schema({
  userId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  credit: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  log: [String]
})
```

**UserSchema**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String
  },
  // etc.....
  credit: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    ref: 'Credit'
  }
})
```

Comment: I don't see `"credit"` in the document you are showing for the "users" collection. Also switch to the JSON view and just copy and paste the "text" instead of screenshots. There is a reason why lower rep accounts can't post "images", and that little period is meant to teach you that lesson.

Comment: I think I know what's the problem, when I do upsert true using findOneAndUpdate for credit, I did not update my user document hence the credit is missing.

Comment: If you have "a lot" that are missing, then you actually can set up a "virtual" with modern releases of mongoose and make it refer to the foreign value that already appears to be there. Also the `$lookup` operator really is the modern way to do this. All `.populate()` does is execute another query to retrieve the results, where as `$lookup` allows this in a single request. At any rate you really don't *"need"* the references in both collections, and really should pick "one direction" and stay with it in the interests of not confusing the update pattern. Like you already appear to have done.